# Trying to make ngTable work with data coming from my API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have a function that is inside a `factory`

```
 API.doRetrieveResults = function(name, id, values, row) {
  // alert(angular.toJson(values));
  var getdata = {
    'operation': 'RetrieveResults',
    'name': name,
    'ds_blockid': id,
    'values': angular.toJson(values),
    'row': row
  };
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: _myurl,
    params: getdata
  });
};
```

This will return an array with over 6K records.

What I want is to display it using ngTable.

I have tried doing something like

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
  page: 1, // show first page
  count: 10 // count per page
}, {
  filterDelay: 300,
  getData: function(params) {
    return API.doRetrieveResults($scope.module, $scope.id, $scope.values, $scope.row).then(function(response) {
      params.total(response.data.result.records.inlineCount);    
      return response.data.result.records;
    });
  }
});
```

And even though while watching the Network tab on chrome's developer tools, I can see the data coming, nothing ever is displayed on my table.

On the other hand something like this

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 10 // count per page
  }, {
    filterDelay: 0,
    getData: function($defer, params) {
      API.doRetrieveResults($scope.module, $scope.id, $scope.values, $scope.row).then(function(response) {
        $scope.totalData = response.data.result.total;
        $scope.data = response.data.result.records;

        var orderedData = params.filter ?
          $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;

        params.total($scope.totalData); // set total for recalc pagination
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
      });
    }
  });
```

Will work, and the various values will be shown on the table, but every time I try to change a page I can see the call to my API being done again and I have to wait once more for all the data to come.

How can I correctly solve this issue, preferably I would like to load my data once, and then pass everything to ngTable to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

What function do you call on a page change?
You already have all rows in $scope.data.

This is an example how you could do it,
in my service I call a webservice and retrieve items filtered by a searchtext:

```js
$scope.data = [];
$scope.dataFiltered = [];

$scope.page = 1;
$scope.numPages = 0;
$scope.rowsPerPage = 10;
$scope.numdata = 0;

$scope.searchData = function() {

  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.dataFiltered = [];
  $scope.page = 1;
  $scope.numPages = 0;
  //$pageLoadingBar.showLoadingBar();

  // call your API retrieve all data once
  YourApiFactory.findData($scope.searchText.value,
    function(dataFound) {

      $scope.data = dataFound;

      $scope.numdata = dataFound.length;
      $scope.numPages = Math.ceil($scope.numdata / $scope.rowsPerPage);

      // Display showing data from to
      $scope.dataTo = $scope.page * $scope.rowsPerPage;
      $scope.dataFrom = $scope.filesTo - $scope.rowsPerPage;

      $scope.updateDataTable ();

      //$pageLoadingBar.hideLoadingBar();
    });

};


$scope.updateDataTable = function() {
  var begin = (($scope.page - 1) * $scope.rowsPerPage),
    end = begin + $scope.rowsPerPage;
  $scope.dataFiltered = $scope.data.slice(begin, end);
}

$scope.nextPage = function() {
  if ($scope.page < $scope.numPages) {
    $scope.page++;
    $scope.updateDataTable ();
  }
};

$scope.previousPage = function() {
  if ($scope.page > 1) {
    $scope.page--;
    $scope.updateDataTable ();
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using a function on a page change, ngTable is. Your answer even though Im sure works, is not exactly what I am going for since I chose to use ngTable.

Comment: this is for ngTable. But you want some kind of paging/filtering.
You can do it at the server side, or on client side.
Normally you have some buttons what page previous/next page and rowsPerPage where you calculate the rows to display.
With ngTable these Information is in the ngTableParams. I suggest to read the documentation there it states you can pass the whole array with your data to the ngTableParams see http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-managed-array. So load the data once and pass it to the ngTableParams.